# ProgrammingError at /register relation "small_small_hr_staffprofile" does not exist

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm running into this error while trying to post a form for creating a user or logging in. I noticed for some reason some tables were not created in my db when i ran python manage.py makemigrations/ migrate. My db settings look ok. Any ideas why this is happening?

ProgrammingError at /register
relation "small_small_hr_staffprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "small_small_hr_staffprofile" ("created", "modif...

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'Swift_hr',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '*********',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that table for a model that you've written? If not, then it's likely one of the apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`. It probably needs to be updated to the latest version of Django or you'll need to write migrations for it to manage the schema.

Comment: Hi thanks that helped,it was an app , i needed to write the migrations #cheers!